# RTK - Is the final position computed by the base or the receiver?

Tags: geolocation, gps

I understand that an RTK base computes a differential correction by comparing its known position and its actual one. But does the base send only a correction signal  to the receiver which then computes its final position (RTCM format for instance), or does the base receive the rover actual position and send back the final corrected rover position?

Ancillary question: from the end user point of view, a GPS receiver provides the same output wether it's RTK aided or not?